# Unable to get resources using getResource()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception, imageicon

I'm trying to get an image to use in a JButton, with the code:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(MineSweeper.class.getResource("C:\\Users\\___\\Documents\\GitHub\\____\\myImage.png"));
buttons[x][y].setIcon(imageIcon);
```

I know the file exists there, however every time I run it I get the error,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
```

Which after looking around says that is the response for not being able to find the file, I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong here. I get this error if I try to use absolute or relative paths, can someone point out what's wrong? I must be over looking something really simple here.

**EDIT:**

As Alan suggested to move the file, I put it into the src folder and it worked fine. Apparently having it else where won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this for setting the image icon

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("myImage.png"));
```

Your image file should be located within the src folder if your using an IDE. If your not using an IDE , put the image in the same folder as your .java files.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ 13.0.1, tried it both with absolute and relative path files, didn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, apparently using an absolute path will not make it work. I moved the files around and it's fine now, thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the path directly like this.

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("c://somepath//image.png");
```

I dont know, how MineSweeper is helpful here

Comment: That's the name of the project that I'm working on, I got it to work though thanks.